# Determining whether an uncountable set of integral equations yield a unique solution

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, inverse-problems

I am interested in the set of numbers $\alpha>0$ for which there exists a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ satisfying 
$$
 \forall r\in \mathbb{R} \qquad f(r) = \int\limits_\mathbb{R}\! g(\alpha r+u) \,d\mu(u)
$$ 
Where $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ is a fixed known function, and $\mu$ is a fixed known probabiliy measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

In particular, how can I tell if this set is a singleton?

Comment: [radon-nikodym derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) is related to this problem, if one has further information about $g$ it may be used. Otherwise $g$ may be related to an ergodic transformation depending on $a$

Comment: for example if $g \in C^n$ it may be expanded in a Taylor-like series wrt to $a$ and then extract appropriate conditions for $a$

Comment: i dont think this can be seen as an uncountable set of simultaneous integral equations for each $a$, as this would imply multiple (uncountable) values for $a$ that produce the same given $f(r)$ at the same time

Comment: @NikosM "[R]adon-[N]ikodym derivative is related to this problem" How so?

Comment: @Did, i guess there are conditions under which the $g$ function can be a radon-nikodym derivative, this was the idea

Comment: @NikosM. Sorry but I fail to see the idea. And asserting that **there is a relation** seems a bit much if all you have is a vague hunch (the "may be related" in the second part of your comment is more proper).

Comment: @Did, ok correct, note that it was said that **may** be related (it all depends on properties of $g$ and $f$, esp. if $f$ is itself a measure), i hope you will agree with that, the comments were meant as potential ideas, not full or necessarily correct solutions, lets not take this too far

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, assume the probability measure can be represented by a density $p(u)$.  Then we want to find $g(x)$ to solve:
$f(r) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\alpha r + u)p(u)du$   (for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$)

This reminds me of a convolution.  So define:
$y(x)=g(-x)$, with Laplace transform $Y(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x)e^{-sx}dx = G(-s)$.
$q(x)=f(-x/\alpha)$, with Laplace transform $Q(s) = \alpha F(-\alpha s)$.

Then your equation becomes:
$q(-\alpha r) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(-\alpha r-u)p(u)du$   (for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$)
So:
$q(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x-u)p(u)du$  (for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$)
Taking the Laplace transform of both sides gives $Q(s) = Y(s)P(s)$, where $Q(s)$ and $P(s)$ are transforms of $q(x)$ and $p(x)$.  Thus:
$G(s) = \frac{\alpha F(\alpha s)}{P(-s)}$.

This "typically" gives a unique solution $g(x)$ for any $\alpha>0$. Of course, you have to worry about details like regions of convergence, and zeros of $P(-s)$.

Oh, I just noticed the extra condition $g(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So you would need an $\alpha$ such that the transform of $\alpha F(\alpha s)/P(-s)$ satisfies that condition...

Comment: Nice try. But, are we sure the Laplace transforms are not identically infinite?

Comment: @Did : That goes under the "of course, you have to worry about details like regions of convergence, and zeros of $P(-s)$." =)